# Azure DevOps Release to Azure SQL without enabling "Allow Access to Azure Services"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

Ive configured a Azure DevOps build and release to an Azure SQL using SSDT/DacPacs. Everything works fine with "Allow Access to Azure Services" but that feels way to open to leave on! is there a way to lock down Azure DevOps to an ip range? or is it simply on or off connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using hosted agents what you can do is:

1. determine agent external ip
2. open up firewall on that ip
3. do your stuff
4. drop that rule

There is no other way, unfortunately.

If you are using your own agent - assign static ip to it and open it up on the firewall, that will work